# extjs: var error = new Error()

Tags: javascript, extjs

A link to [ext-all-debug.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/6.0.0/ext-all-debug.js) is as the follows https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/6.0.0/ext-all-debug.js. It has the following code. Which file includes the definition of class `Error` in the following code?

```
    var error = new Error();
```

Comment: It's part of the JavaScript language.

Comment: More on that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

Answer (score 1):

`Error` lives on the global object in JavaScript.